# SendGrid - Signature verification getting failed all time

Tags: twilio, webhooks, sendgrid, ecdsa, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to implement Sendgrid Signature verification. I have configured the calling function in Sendgrid webhook.
I was getting signature and timestamp from sendgrid webhook but verifications are failing all the time,
The agenda is whenever mails are getting triggered from the project by using Sendgrid API key, the webhook events will be triggered and fetching the signature and timestamp
from the webhook and process the Signature verification. Once verification done save the payload into Database.

Here is my code

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/events")  
public void webhookEvents(@RequestBody Set\<EmailEvents\> emailEvents, @RequestHeader("X-Twilio-      Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp") String timestamp,
@RequestHeader("X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Signature") String signature) throws    NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException, IOException,   SignatureException, InvalidKeyException {

log.info("Inside webhookEvents...");
log.info("Signature ----->"+signature);
log.info("Timestamp ----->"+timestamp);

boolean verify = emailDataService.verifySendgridSignature(emailEvents,signature,timestamp);
log.info("Signature Verification : "+verify);
emailDataService.webhookEvents(emailEvents);
}
```

EmailEvents:

```
public class EmailEvents {

public String email;

public int timestamp;
@SerializedName("smtp-id")
public String smtp_id;

public String event;
public ArrayList<String> category;
public String sg_event_id;
public String sg_message_id;

private String useragent;

private String ip;

private boolean sg_machine_open;

private String emailUUID;

private String sentDate;

}
```

EmailDataService:

```
private EventWebhook ew =  new EventWebhook();
final String publicKey = "XXXXXX";

public boolean verifySendgridSignature(Set<EmailEvents> emailEvents,String signature,String timestamp) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchProviderException, IOException, SignatureException, InvalidKeyException {

    String payload = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(emailEvents);
    final ECPublicKey ellipticCurvePublicKey = ew.ConvertPublicKeyToECDSA(publicKey);
    final boolean valid = ew.VerifySignature(ellipticCurvePublicKey,payload , signature, timestamp);
    System.out.println("Valid Signature: " + valid);
    return valid;
}
```

EventWebhook :

```
public class EventWebhook {

public java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey ConvertPublicKeyToECDSA(String publicKey)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    byte[] publicKeyInBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    return (ECPublicKey) factory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyInBytes));
}

public boolean VerifySignature(ECPublicKey publicKey, String payload, String signature, String timestamp)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, IOException {
    return VerifySignature(publicKey, payload.getBytes(), signature, timestamp);
}

public boolean VerifySignature(ECPublicKey publicKey, byte[] payload, String signature, String timestamp)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, IOException {

    // prepend the payload with the timestamp
    final ByteArrayOutputStream payloadWithTimestamp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    payloadWithTimestamp.write(timestamp.getBytes());
    payloadWithTimestamp.write(payload);

    // create the signature object
    final Signature signatureObject = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "BC");
    signatureObject.initVerify(publicKey);
    signatureObject.update(payloadWithTimestamp.toByteArray());

    // decode the signature
    final byte[] signatureInBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

    // verify the signature
    return signatureObject.verify(signatureInBytes);
  }
 }
```

Comment: hey @dhanyesh did you get the solution for this problem, I am having same issue